# Add ViewController vs. Edit ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am trying to decide on a design pattern. I have an app where the user adds an entry to a Core Data database. They also should have the ability to edit that entry at a later time as well. Both views basically show the same data, only one is for editing what has already been added.

I am not sure if I should have two very similar separate view controllers or if I should use some kind of inheritance to set this up, or if there is some other idea that I'm not thinking of.

I appreciate your input.

Comment: I'd share the nib file and create two separate `UIViewController` subclasses.

Comment: I mostly treat it as both being editing operations.  In one case, it just happens that the information being edited is default values...frequently empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered a similar item to solve and ended up going with the using the same `UIViewController` to do both operations.  Both use cases are fundamentally the same: a user enters information and then saves.  The validation of the data is the same, saving is the same, the presentation is the same.  They only vary on whether your model object already exists or not.  Consider the following example:

.h file:

```
@interface WHItemViewController : UITableViewController

//  This is the only attribute we really need to expose in our header
//  so that the presenting view controller can set the model object when editing
@property (nontatomic, retain) WHItem* item;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@interface WHItemViewController()

// Other 'private' properties and methods

- (void)didSelectSaveButton:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation WHItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.item) { // setup the UI with the model object, if present.
        self.fooText.text = self.item.foo;
        self.barText.text = self.item.bar;
        self.bazText.text = self.item.baz;
    }
}

- (void)didSelectSaveButton:(id)sender {
    if (!self.item) {
        WHItem* item = nil;

        //  create a new instance from your managed object context 
        //  and set it to the item property

        self.item = item;
    }

    self.item.foo = self.fooText.text;
    self.item.bar = self.barText.text;
    self.item.baz = self.bazText.text

    NSError* error = nil;
    [WHDataAccess sharedInstance].managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // Error handling, etc.
}

//  Other methods

@end
```

The sole purpose of this view controller is to create presentation for editing and saving model object data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation, and I use one view controller for both. If I pass an entity, it will edit that entity. If I don't it's a new entity. In viewDidLoad I check if an entity is set, and if it isn't, I create one. Then I go on to fill the textfields and other information. If it's a new entity, the attributes will be empty or have a default value, and so will the views in my view controller. When the user is ready, I don't have to check whether to update or to insert, as an entity was already inserted at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm going with this method of design.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pattern like this:

```
#import "ItemViewController.h"

@protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AddItemViewController : ItemViewController
{
    id <AddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol AddItemViewControllerDelegate
    - (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishWithSave:   (BOOL)save;
@end
```

The AddItemController simply subclasses the ItemViewController that I use for editing and displaying existing objects.

Then in the implementation I do something like this:

```
#import "AddItemViewController.h"

@implementation AddItemViewController
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    // Set up the undo manager and set editing state to YES.
    [self setUpUndoManager];
    self.editing = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self cleanUpUndoManager];
    [super viewDidUnload];  
}

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishWithSave:NO];
}

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    [delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishWithSave:YES];
}

// ... other stuff.

@end
```